# jquery hover not applying to child node

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I need the hover function on "type of worker" and "where do you work?" on the right sidebar (under the contact for) to be a lot cleaner. What i need is for the child ul to remain visible when i hover over the ul and not just the parent link right now if i mouse out of the parent link

Here is my code

```
<div class="nav_item">
<div class="nav_item_link" id="clickMe2" href="#"><img src="http://50.28.46.210/dev/obryan/wp-content/themes/wp-foundation/images/compassicon.png" class="nav_icons">

<h5>Where Do You Work?</h5></a>
</div>
<ul id="clickEvent2" class="worker_list">
<li><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/obryan/where-do-you-work/pacific-ocean/">Pacific Ocean</a></li>
<li><a href=""http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/obryan/where-do-you-work/atlantic-ocean/">Atlantic Ocean</a></li>
<li><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/obryan/where-do-you-work/gulf-of-mexico/">Gulf of Mexico</a></li>
<li><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/obryan/where-do-you-work/bering-sea/">Bering Sea</a></li>
<li><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/obryan/where-do-you-work/great-lakes/">Great Lakes</a></li>
<li><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/obryan/where-do-you-work/international-waters/">International Waters</a></li>
<li><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/obryan/where-do-you-work/mississippi-river/">Mississippi River</a></li>
<li><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/obryan/where-do-you-work/ohio-river/">Ohio River</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And here is my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#clickMe').hover(function() {
 $("#clickEvent").fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: There is no `clickMe` in your example. Please clarify.

Comment: ...and if you want the hover to stay open while over the `ul`, then why isn't the event bound to the `.nav_item` instead? EDIT: Borrowing @Tim Wasson's jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4dvbL/1/

Answer (score 1):

Posting as an answer as requested: http://jsfiddle.net/hgEV9/

```
$('#clickMe').on("mouseenter",function() {
 $("#clickEvent2").fadeToggle("slow");
})
```

HTML:

```
<div class="nav_item">
<a class="nav_item_link" id="clickMe" href="#"><img src="http://50.28.46.210/dev/obryan/wp-content/themes/wp-foundation/images/compassicon.png" class="nav_icons"></a>
</div>
<h5>Where Do You Work?</h5>

<ul id="clickEvent2" class="worker_list">
<li><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/obryan/where-do-you-work/pacific-ocean/">Pacific Ocean</a></li>
<li><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/obryan/where-do-you-work/atlantic-ocean/">Atlantic Ocean</a></li>
<li><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/obryan/where-do-you-work/gulf-of-mexico/">Gulf of Mexico</a></li>
<li><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/obryan/where-do-you-work/bering-sea/">Bering Sea</a></li>
<li><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/obryan/where-do-you-work/great-lakes/">Great Lakes</a></li>
<li><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/obryan/where-do-you-work/international-waters/">International Waters</a></li>
<li><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/obryan/where-do-you-work/mississippi-river/">Mississippi River</a></li>
<li><a href="http://dev.trafficdigitalagency.com/obryan/where-do-you-work/ohio-river/">Ohio River</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```